# React Native Reanimated - how to create animated circles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I am trying to create animating circles using React Native. There's a button in the middle, and when the button is clicked, animation will start. I referred this website to create the effect:
https://www.codedaily.io/tutorials/Creating-Animated-Rings-with-React-Native-Reanimated

With my current code, only one circle is animating at a time (like in right picture) I want to make circles animating at the same time like in the left picture (circles animate at the same time with delay)
Can someone help me achieving this?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import Animated, {
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
  withDelay,
  withRepeat,
  withTiming,
  interpolate,
} from "react-native-reanimated";

export default function Circle({ delay, scale }) {
  const ring = useSharedValue(0);

  const ringStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      opacity: 0.3 - ring.value,
      transform: [
        {
          scale: interpolate(ring.value, [0, 1], [1, 9]),
        },
      ],
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    ring.value = withDelay(
      delay,
      withRepeat(
        withTiming(1, {
          duration: 2400,
        }),
        -1,
        false
      )
    );
  }, [delay]);
  return <Animated.View style={[styles.ring, ringStyle]} />;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ring: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: 140,
    height: 140,
    borderRadius: 70,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)",
  },
});
```

```
<Circle delay={0} scale={1} />
<Circle delay={600} scale={1} />
<Circle delay={1200} scale={1} />
<Circle delay={1800} scale={1} />
```

[image]